# HTTP attacking post parameters

Tags: asp.net, http, post, get

My department has an external department that perform scans on our sites before going live to test for vulnerabilities. One vulnerability came back regarding how errors are displayed. I've fixed that as far as I believe.

I wanted to duplicate their test before having them scan again since there is a multi-day delay from when I submit my scan and when it performed/analyzed/sent back to me. Here is the test they performed:

```
1. Navigate to preset starting location for analysis
        URL: <mysite>

2. Submit form using the following URL and form values
        URL: <mysite>
        Form Values:
                __EVENTTARGET = 
                __EVENTARGUMENT = 
                __VIEWSTATE = <viewstate_stuff>
                __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = <viewstate_stuff>
                __EVENTVALIDATION = <eventvalidation stuff>
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24UserName = foo
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24Password = foo
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24RememberMe = on
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24LoginButton = Log%20In

3. Attack discovered GET URL
        URL: <mysite>
        Post Parameters Attacked:
                __EVENTTARGET = 
                __EVENTARGUMENT = 
                __VIEWSTATE = <viewstate_stuff>
                __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = <viewstate_stuff>
                __EVENTVALIDATION = <eventvalidation stuff>
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24UserName = foo
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24Password = foo
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24RememberMe = on
                ctl00%24MainContent%24loginBox%24LoginButton = web.config
```

How do I do something like this? I feel like I should know this already.

Comment: If you can post more information about your requirements, that would be helpful. Are you just trying to send a sequence of requests to an endpoint? Can you just use [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do that? Does it specifically need to be done in a browser? Can you rig something up with [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)?

Comment: it does not need to be done in a browser (unless there is a browser add-on that can be used). essentially I just need to hack my own website as their testing software does: send a request, see the reply, alter values, send request back

Comment: or perhaps stackoverflow is the wrong place for this post?